# Yii2 How can i set the db config in new Query without use all(), one() or other execution method?

Tags: database, activerecord, model, yii2, multipeer-connectivity

I have 2 models on my search function joined by a field an I want to create an `ActiveDataProvider` for my `GridView`. This is what I have so far:

My yii db config:

```
db => users logs data;
db1 => system data;
```

`Model1` and `Model2` are in `db1`

```
public function search($params)
{
    // (...)
    $query1 = Model1::find();
    $query2 = Model2::find();
    $query1->select(
            new Expression ("'Data model1: ' Model"),
            'model1.id',
            'model1.columns',
       )->jointWith(['mODEL2'])
       ->andWhere(new Expression ('model1.id || model1.columns != model2.id || model2.columns'));

    $query2->select(
            new Expression ("'Data model2: ' Model"),
            'model2.id',
            'model2.columns',
        )->jointWith(['mODEL1'])
        ->andWhere(new Expression ('model1.id || model1.columns != model2.id || model2.columns'));

    $unionQuery = (new  Query())->from(['dummy_name'=>$query1->union($query2)]);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
         'query'=>$unionQuery,
    ]);
    // (...)

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

And the server database exception:

> the table or view not exist

In my models (1 and 2) I do specific that I use the `db1` connection, but how can I do that in the `$unionQuery` without use `$unionQuery->all(Yii::$app->db1)`?

That do not work.

Comment: your code and your question seems without sense  to me  .. try explain  your goal  .. and not simply an assertion  .

Comment: I don't think the `multipeer-connectivity` tag is appropriate here as that refers to an iOS framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In your case query is executed at ActiveDataProvider level so you
>   should set ActiveDataProvider::$db property with correct db
>   connection.

awesome thanks a lot this works

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query'=>$unionQuery,
    'db'=>Yii::$app->db1,      
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can i do that in the $unionQuery without use $unionQuery->all(Yii::$app->db1)???

You cannot. DB connection should be specified on query execution.

In your case query is executed at `ActiveDataProvider` level so you should set [`ActiveDataProvider::$db`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-activedataprovider#$db-detail) property with correct db connection.

Comment: @RacielBritoDorta If it works for you, please accept the answer.